# Not being able to add a Button at the bottom

Tags: android, xml

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GetAttendanceFromDatabase"
    android:background="@drawable/animation_back_grad1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="Your Record"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp" />    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalLectures"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Total Lectures Delivered : 10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/attendancRrecordList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@color/custom_list_back" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I just want to add an exit button just below the `ListView`, but when I write the button code it goes out form the layout?

I have given a margin Bottom to the list, but it still is not working.
I have tried inserting the `Button` in inner layout and also tried inserting the list view inside the inner layout, but nothing is working for me!

[image: this is I am getting]

Answer (score 0):

This will do your job !

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="16">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="Your Record"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalLectures"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Total Lectures Delivered : 10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/attendancRrecordList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="11"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Exit Button"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please tell me how this weight will do my job!  I have solved that by putting both list view and button in inner relative layout . btw thanks for your answer

Comment: Weight sum & layout weight splits the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use weights  copy paste this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
android:padding="5dp"
android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="Your Record"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalLectures"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Total Lectures Delivered : 10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
  </LinearLayout>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/attendancRrecordList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="asdasd"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please tell me how this weight will do my job!  I have solved that by putting both list view and button in inner relative layout . btw thanks for your answer

Comment: weightsum tell total wieght then layout_weight  tell you how much weight should be given to specific  layout from total weight i-e weightsum